# How do I inspect the SQL Server side SSL certificate used in SqlConnection?

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server-2008, ssl, certificate

I use `SqlConnection` class to connect to a SQL Server using a connection string with "encrypt data" set. I want to access the server side SSL certificate and find when it expires. If I used `HttpWebRequest` I would access its `ServicePoint` property that provides access to the server certificate. Looks like `SqlConnection` does not provide a similar property.

How do I access the server certificate when using `SqlConnection`?

Comment: Is the encryption set on the SQL Server side? Client side encryption is optional and set in the client. Server side encryption is mandatory and set in SQL Server tools. So, if server side encryption is enabled, the client doesn't need the certificate at all. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189067(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: @gbn: I want the server certificate, not the client one.

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure you don't need it.

The public key is sent as part of the connection handshaking

I have SQL Server encryption enabled and none of the client code requires the certificate

Comment: I want to find the expiration date, so I do need the certificate.

Comment: @sharptooth: why use the SQLConnection class then? This is for SQL Server connections. You'd need to use WMI or such because the cert is outside of SQL Server

Comment: I want to be damn sure that I'm checking the certificate that was used to establish the connection, so I have to get it from `SqlConnection`.

Comment: @sharptooth: sorry, this makes no sense. The cert is server side, not available to code or calls within SQL Server

Comment: It does make sense. If you open `https://twitter.com` in your browser you can see the public part of the site SSL certificate. I want to do the same with my `SqlConnection`.

Comment: @sharptooth: you can't via SQLConnection. Simple